# Include files DataTimePicker in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, datepicker

I try to add DataTimePickier to my plugin. DataPicker works very well, but DataTimePicker doesn't want to work at all. I click on the input and nothing happens.

[DataTimePicker author's site](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

In normal .php file, where DataTimePicker works perfectly I include :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" />
</head>
<body>

            <input type="text" class="datepicker"/>

<!--loading jQuery and other library-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

In WordPress plugin file I try to inclue the same files like in normal .php file:

```
 function add_datapicker()
{

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-slider' );

    wp_register_script('add_time', plugins_url('/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js', __FILE__));

    wp_register_script('add_datatime', plugins_url('/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js', __FILE__));
    wp_register_script('add_script', plugins_url('/script.js', __FILE__));

    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'add_datatime' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'add_time' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'add_script' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_datapicker' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_datapicker' );
```

In normal DataPicker  (without time) i had included code like bellow:

```
    function myplugin_add_datapicker() {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
        wp_register_script('add_data', plugins_url('/js/datepicker.js', __FILE__));

        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');

        wp_enqueue_script( 'add_data' );

    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_add_datapicker' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_add_datapicker' );
```

And it was working perfectly. So, where is a mistake?

Script.cs is the same file like datapicker.js. Content bellow:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker(
        {
            timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
            stepHour: 1,
            stepMinute: 1,
            stepSecond: 1,
            timeText: 'Czas',
            hourText: 'Godziny',
            minuteText: 'Minuty',
            secondText: 'Sekundy',
            currentText: 'Aktualny czas',
            closeText: 'Gotowe'
        });

    jQuery(function($){
        $.datepicker.regional['pl'] = {
            closeText: 'Zamknij',
            prevText: '<Poprzedni',
            nextText: 'Następny>',
            currentText: 'Dziś',
            monthNames: ['Styczeń','Luty','Marzec','Kwiecień','Maj','Czerwiec',
                'Lipiec','Sierpień','Wrzesień','Październik','Listopad','Grudzień'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Sty','Lu','Mar','Kw','Maj','Cze',
                'Lip','Sie','Wrz','Pa','Lis','Gru'],
            dayNames: ['Niedziela','Poniedziałek','Wtorek','Środa','Czwartek','Piątek','Sobota'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Nie','Pn','Wt','Śr','Czw','Pt','So'],
            dayNamesMin: ['N','Pn','Wt','Śr','Cz','Pt','So'],
            weekHeader: 'Tydz',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ''};

        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['pl']);

    });


});
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you can't get it working, then you can't possibly know that "uncomment line 1" _isn't_ part of the solution. Can you provide more details of what happens? Any errors in your browser's script debug console etc.?

Comment: I uncomment line 1, because it's the same like wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider'); . I thought that maybe is not the same, so i tried every combination.When I use DataPicker everything is ok. But when I try to add DataTimePicker , calendar doesn't show at all.

Answer (score 0):

I can see several issues. Firstly you are including the scripts with the wrong action call of `'init'` instead of `'wp_enqueue_scripts'`. Another smaller point is that it is good practise to prefix all your function calls with a unique identifier string for your plugin so that you're not overwriting some other plugins function. Your add action call should look like this...

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_add_datapicker' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_add_datapicker' );
```

(replace myplugin with whatever works for your plugin, i usually use a 3 letter identifier eg `hhf_add_datepicker`)

Your next issue (and probably main issue) is that you have not included any dependencies when you register your scripts. As `datepicker.js` (i presume) relies on `jquery-ui-datepicker` you need to tell wordpress that. eg...

```
wp_register_script( 'datepicker', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/file/path.js', 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
```

You can find out more about how to enqueue scripts in the [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). There are also a few typos and mistakes in your code, a missing semi-colon and not sure what filepath you're linking to but it doesn't look right. assuming that your `datepicker.js` file is in a directory called 'js' in your plugin directory your code should look like this...

```
function myplugin_add_datapicker() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
    wp_register_script('timepicker', plugins_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js', 'jquery');
    wp_register_script( 'datepicker', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/datepicker.js', 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );

    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'timepicker' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'datepicker' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_add_datapicker' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_add_datapicker' );
```

The final thing you may want to address is that you have not used any conditional logic to tell Wordpress when specifically to enqueue your scripts. At the moment Wordpress will add all your scripts to every page inside and outside the admin area regardless of wether they're needed or not resulting in a higher possibility of conflicts and slower page loading.

I hope that helps

Regards

Dan

Comment: Thanks, that's work. But i want to add DataTimePicker. I have to add more files and I do something wrong.

Comment: Can you give more detail? Have you put the DateTimePIcker script file into your /js/ directory? have you dried to enqueue it? Is the file present in the page source and just misbehaving or is it missing completely?

Comment: Yes, i have edtited my post. look now. It's a beta version, so i have js in main plugin directory

Comment: Just updated my post to include your timepicker file properly. Could you use your browser to view the page source and check to see if the timepicker script is present. If it is then the problem will probably be an error in your datepicker.js file.

Comment: Lol i check this in browser and "plugins_url( __FILE__ )" gave bad path. Additionally plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) give dobule slash. I correct this and i have 'white page'. It's when I add wp_register_script('timepicker', plugins_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js');

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific, what exactly is your browser console saying?

Comment: Now, nothing. I have white page and in source code only meta title and this script : 

<script type="text/javascript">
addLoadEvent = function(func){if(typeof jQuery!="undefined")jQuery(document).ready(func);else if(typeof wpOnload!='function'){wpOnload=func;}else{var oldonload=wpOnload;wpOnload=function(){oldonload();func();}}};
var ajaxurl = '/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
pagenow = 'post',
typenow = 'post',
adminpage = 'post-php',
thousandsSeparator = ' ',
decimalPoint = ',',
isRtl = 0;
</script>